# How to check memory leaks using memory usages of a process?

Tags: c++, linux, memory-leaks

```
int ParseLine(char* line){
   int i = strlen(line);
   const char* p = line;
   while(*p < '0' || *p > '9') p++;    // Search until a number is found.
   line[i - 3] = '\0'; // Remove " kB"
   i = atoi(p);
   return i;
}

int GetCurrentVirtualMem(){
   std::string cur_proc;
   cur_proc = "/proc/" + std::to_string((int)getpid()) + "/status";

   FILE* fs = fopen(cur_proc.c_str(), "r");
   int result = -1;
   char line[128];

   while(fgets(line, 128, fs) != NULL){
       if(strncmp(line, "VmSize:", 7) == 0){
           result = ParseLine(line);
           break;
       }
   }
   fclose(fs);
   fs = NULL;  //garly modify, for test memory problem

   return result;
}

int GetCurrentMem(){
   std::string cur_proc;
   cur_proc = "/proc/" + std::to_string((int)getpid()) + "/status";

   FILE* fs = fopen(cur_proc.c_str(), "r");
   int result = -1;
   char line[128];

   while(fgets(line, 128, fs) != NULL){
       if(strncmp(line, "VmRSS:", 6) == 0){
           result = ParseLine(line);
           break;
       }
   }
   fclose(fs);
   fs = NULL;  //garly modify, for test memory problem
   return result;
}
```

I'm trying to check memory leaks but I don't understand physical memory and virtual memory clearly. So I just printed both using the functions above.

```
float curr_mem = (float)GetCurrentMem() / 1000;
float curr_vir_mem = (float)GetCurrentVirtualMem() / 1000;
std::cout << "Using memory(" << std::to_string((int)getpid()) << "): " << curr_mem << ", " << curr_vir_mem << std::endl;
```

If I check the changes of physical memory or virtual memory, which one should I take a look at?
Both? or one of them?

And I found that even if there are no memory leaks the memory values are changed.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);

   float prev_mem = 0;
   float prev_vir_mem = 0;
   while(true){

       int* mem_leak = new int[100];


       float curr_mem = (float)GetCurrentMem() / 1000;
       float curr_vir_mem = (float)GetCurrentVirtualMem() / 1000;

       if(prev_mem != curr_mem || prev_vir_mem != curr_vir_mem){
           prev_mem = curr_mem ;
           prev_vir_mem = curr_vir_mem;

           std::cout << "Using memory(" << std::to_string((int)getpid()) << "): " << curr_mem << ", " << curr_vir_mem << std::endl;
       }

       delete[] mem_leak;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

After an hour of running the code above, it showed the changes in the memory

```
Using memory(3303): 28.296, 250.788 
Using memory(3303): 28.652, 250.788 
Using memory(3303): 28.916, 250.788
```

So is this method fine to check memory leak or not?
I used "Valgrind" but it didn't show any memory leak message from my code(not the above code. It is too huge to upload here. It is over 30000 lines.). But it showed memory changes in the long-term running test(about 1-week).

Please let me know how to check memory leaks correctly without using other software(such as Valgrind).

Comment: Although it is not answer for your problem, how about switching to C++ filestream headers and corresponding I/O, and using the shared_ptr or unique_ptr? It would help you from the memory leak problems. And Google about RAII. It is a must-know for every C++ programmers.

Comment: `but I don't understand physical memory and virtual memory` - The problem of memory leaks has nothing to do with 'physical memory vs virtual memory'.

Comment: Modern memory management is neat stuff. when a program asks for memory most systems just say yes **and don't give them any.** Some time later if the memory is used, then the system will spend the time actually providing memory. `mem_leak`'s never used, so it won't get any actual memory. Some virtual memory will be allocated, but it's a pretty small increase and might be lost in the noise or space that was reserved, freed and secretly held onto for later reuse.

Comment: Don't forget your program could be freeing all of it's memory, and not triggering valgrind, but freeing it much later than you wanted. For example, a `vector` the program keeps adding to but never empties. When the vector's destroyed at program exit, the memory's freed, but it could have grown to a gazillion bytes in the meantime.

Comment: The amount of physical memory the program can use is also affected by other programs competing for it. If there is great activity, parts of the program might get swapped out (virtual memory). If there is no competition, Windows is known to not bother to reclaim free memory until it is needed for something else.

Comment: @K.R.Park If I cannot find any solution, I should replace pointers to the smart pointers. Thank you.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you. It is more complicated than I thought. And I tried to check all the std::vector but I couldn't find any problem.

Comment: @BoP I understood. So just checking memory usage doesn't show results from memory leaks. Thank you.

Comment: Checking memory usage can show signs of a leak, but they aren't necessarily obvious.  The physical memory in use may not increase significantly because the leaked memory is no longer being accessed and has been pushed off to swap space to make room storage that is in use. You should see the virtual memory increasing because whether or not the memory is in use, the addressing has been assigned. Hunting and killing a leak in a large program is non-trivial, and it's made all the worse if the memory isn't really leaked, as in it is still accessible, but forgotten.

Comment: If valgrind doesn't spot a leak, odds are more likely that you have "forgotten" memory. Could be in a `vector`, could be in a `std::string`, a stream, any library or custom container, or managed by a smart pointer or other RAII wrapper class. As a project grows, there are more and more places to hide stuff, so it might be time to back up and pull out the hacksaw to split things up and check the pieces individually.

Comment: @user4581301 Ok I get it. I will check the code again very carefully. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to check for memory leaks on Linux using a process image from an process that has not been instrumented in any way.

https://github.com/vmware/chap (free open source) does this.

First you gather a core:

```
echo 0x37 > /proc/<pid-of-your-process>/coredump_filter
gcore <pid-of-your-process>
```

Then you open the core in chap:

```
chap <core-just-created-by-gcore>
```

To check for the classic kind of leak (objects that can no longer be reached) you can use the following commands from the chap prompt:

```
count leaked
```

That tells you how many objects were leaked.

```
describe leaked /showUpTo 100
```

That describes each leaked object, gives a hex dump of up to 0x100 bytes of each object and gives you the count at the end.

Various other commands are available but I don't want to repeat the user's manual.

Comment: I appreciate. I'm trying with this method.